# kafka-python publish to all consumers

Tags: python-2.7, apache-kafka, kafka-python

Is there a way to publish a message to all the partitions?
I am using kafka-python==1.4.3.

Understood from the documentation that

> key (optional) – a key to associate with the message. Can be used to
>   determine which partition to send the message to. If partition is None
>   (and producer’s partitioner config is left as default), then messages
>   with the same key will be delivered to the same partition (but if key
>   is None, partition is chosen randomly). Must be type bytes, or be
>   serializable to bytes via configured key_serializer.

but was not able to find any clue if the message can be published to all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Understood that there is no direct API but it can be achieved by combining two calls.

```
partitions_for(topic) - Returns set of all known partitions for the topic.

send(topic, value=None, key=None, headers=None, partition=None, timestamp_ms=None) - Publish a message to a topic.
```